# Is it possible that controller parameters in MVC application are required and routing does not match empty parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, routes

having an action `Detail(int id)` on a `ProductController`, I can access by

```
/Product/Detail/32
```

but if I do

```
Product/Detail
```

I also access the same controller with no `id` passed. How can I make the parameter required, otherwise returns 404 (don't execute the controller action at all, like not matching route)

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id) {
    // some fancy code that get the product by id
    return View()
}
```

routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Application", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } defaults);
```

I know I can do if (product not found) return `HttpNotFound()` and that works for most scenarios, but i was wondering if there's a way so the controller action is not even reached without passing the argument

EDIT:

```
/ <-- homepage
/Product/List <-- List of products
/Product/Detail <-- return 404
/Product/Detail/10 <-- Product Details id 10
```

right now, i want to know if there's any way to support this kind of "simple" scenario.
Actions on the controller are:

```
ApplicationController{
    public ActionResult Index() {}
}

ProductController {
    public ActionResult List(){}
    public ActionResult Detail(int id){}
}
```

current routing is only the default:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Application", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Adding the suggested routing does not work as expected because either returns a `404` on `/Product/Detail` BUT also return `404` on `/Product/List` and `/`.

OR (other suggestion)

`ActionResult Detail(int id)` is invoked either without sending the param in the request, which is the purpose of this question to know if it's possible to do NOT MATCH a url `/Product/Detail` without it's id parameter at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Change routing

Just accomodate routing for it and remove `id` default to be optional parameter:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // defaults
);
```

but those defaults are never going to be used so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}" // URL with parameters
);
```

This is the actual route that needs to be defined.

Your `controller` and `action` aren't ever going to be omitted from the URL as `id` is required and is the last one in URL definition which means that the first pair will have to be there as well.

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you need but, based on the current state of your question this should do the trick for you. But if you require your id, to have some predefined value, you can give it a different value in your route definition:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 1 } // defaults
);
```

This makes it possible that all three can be omitted from the URL and all of them would have a particular value.

### Route constraints to define `id` format

You can also use route constraints to tell routing how URL parameters should look like. Since your `id` seems to must be numeric this is also *one of the possibilities*:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }, // defaults
    new { id = "\d+" } // constraints
);
```

---

## After your edit

There are actually two solutions to your problem.

1. Proper routing to define required `id` for some routes
2. Action method selector filter to declaratively mark actions that they require certain parameters

### Solution 1: Routing

This one defines several routing definitions but hardcode your actions that require `id` parameter:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "RequiresId",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    null,
    new { action = "Detail" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}" // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { action = "(?!Detail).+" } // any action except "Detail"
);
```

First route defines that all controllers with action method `Detail` require `id` parameter. This is simple as long as **all** controllers with these actions have same requirements (which may likely be in your case). But when this is not true it will become more complicated because you'll have to provide constraints per controller.

### Solution 2: Action Method Selector Filter

This solution requires only default route with optional `id`. A custom action method selector filter (which is rarely known and seldom used) will help you write code like:

```
[RequiresRouteValues("id, name")]
public ActionResult Detail(int id, string name)
{
    ...
}
```

You'd put this on those methods that require it. If that particular parameter will not be present Controller action invoker will not be able to find a suitable method hence returning a 404.

I've talked about this in much detail [on my blog](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/improving-aspnet-mvc-maintainability.html). It also include filter's code which looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an attribute that is used to restrict action method selection based on route values.
/// </summary>
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1019:DefineAccessorsForAttributeArguments")]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class RequiresRouteValuesAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    #region Properties
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets required route value names.
    /// </summary>
    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> Names { get; private set; }
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether to include form fields in the check.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if form fields should be included; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    public bool IncludeFormFields { get; set; }
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether to include query variables in the check.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     <c>true</c> if query variables should be included; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool IncludeQueryVariables { get; set; }
 
    #endregion
 
    #region Constructors
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RequiresRouteValuesAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    private RequiresRouteValuesAttribute()
    {
        this.IncludeFormFields = true;
        this.IncludeQueryVariables = true;
    }
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RequiresRouteValuesAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="commaSeparatedNames">Comma separated required route values names.</param>
    public RequiresRouteValuesAttribute(string commaSeparatedNames)
        : this((commaSeparatedNames ?? string.Empty).Split(','))
    {
        // does nothing
    }
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RequiresRouteValuesAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="names">Required route value names.</param>
    public RequiresRouteValuesAttribute(IEnumerable<string> names)
        : this()
    {
        if (names == null || names.Count().Equals(0))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("names");
        }
 
        // store names
        this.Names = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(names.Select(val => val.Trim()).ToList());
    }
 
    #endregion
 
    #region ActionMethodSelectorAttribute implementation
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the action method selection is valid for the specified controller context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controllerContext">The controller context.</param>
    /// <param name="methodInfo">Information about the action method.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the action method selection is valid for the specified controller context; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        }
 
        // always include route values
        HashSet<string> uniques = new HashSet<string>(controllerContext.RouteData.Values.Keys);
 
        // include form fields if required
        if (this.IncludeFormFields)
        {
            uniques.UnionWith(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys);
        }
 
        // include query string variables if required
        if (this.IncludeQueryVariables)
        {
            uniques.UnionWith(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.AllKeys);
        }
 
        // determine whether all route values are present
        return this.Names.All(val => uniques.Contains(val));
    }
 
    #endregion
}
```

The first one makes things complicated in applications with several controllers and different constraints related to them. The second one is elegant and applies to simple and complex scenarios.

I would of course choose **solution 2**. But take me as a biased developer in this case.

Comment: it fallsback to default route if no id is passed. so this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Bart: What do you mean? You **only defined** default route anyway? Is there any other route we're not aware of? Can you make yourself more clear what seems to be wrong?

Comment: @Bart: can you please tell me what scenarios you'd like to cover (by editing your answer and clearing this thing. Do you want `id` to be **always** present for any request or just for certain requests (or maybe just a single one)? Do you know how id should look like? would you like to execute some code when `id` is not provided or would you like MVC to handle such erroneous situation? Seems your question isn't really clear.

Comment: sure, sorry for misunderstanding on not being clear. I updated the question to make it a little bit more clear. Hope it helps :D

Comment: @Bart: I've edited my answer. Both solutions will solve your problem. It's on you to decide which one seems to be better in your case. Surely second one improves maintainability of your app.

Comment: @Bart: Arguably the best thing from client standpoint would of course be to have a RESTful approach to your routes where `/Products` would return a list and `/Products/1` would return individual product details. But server-side isn't that simple. *One of my articles still waiting to be written to completely cover full RESTful scenario.*

Comment: I want controller to execute routes only if the exact match Controller/Action/Params is provided. If I declare a controller something like : DoSomething(int a, string b) i don't want to be executed at all if either a or b is not in the request. is that possible? I don't see how that could be possible.

Comment: excellent, solution 2 is perfect. Solution 1 does NOT work tho, because it always fall back to default route if no id is present (or am I missing something?). Either way, solution 2 is the way to go. THANKS!

Comment: @Bart: The first solution should work just as well (true, I edited it a bit), as long as you're trying to access some **Detail** (`/Product/Detail/32` should be caught by first route definition). But I agree that second solution is definitely more elegant and much more flexible and uses MVC extensibility points without sacrificing future changes to your routing.

Comment: @RoberKoritnik a just tested it out, if I go to /Product/Detail (without id) it matches the second rule and behaves the same as not having the route in the first place so no, it's not working as a solution. The route /Product/Detail will be matched to the Detail(int id) action.

Comment: @Bart: Yes that's because I forgot to add an additional constraint on the second route (or reverse their definitions with positive regular expression). I've added that so you can try as well if you want to, but if you're staying with solution 2, you can just ignore solution  one anyway.

Comment: I see how to implementing it now with routes. I'm staying with solution 2 but its nice you fixed it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the Id as optional

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Application", action = "Index"} );
```

If you want to keep id optional then you could have a different route defined for product details

```
routes.MapRoute("ProductDetails", "product/details/{id}");
```

which requires an Id and leave your original default route as is.

Comment: doing so will make routing not match Product/Index, or any route that doesn't have an ID as parameter.

Comment: same behaviour since when there is no match for product/details/{id} it fallback to default route...

Comment: why not display something like "There is no such product" instead of a 404?

Comment: that's an option, im actually asking if there's a way to make route not match at all and behave like if someone typed /Product/GFDASGASDFAEW <-- a not-found / not-existant url.

Comment: yes but if you want the generic route as well then this will always look for an action called GFDASGASDFAEW

Comment: exactly, the same i want when it looks for an action called Detail() <-- that doesn't exist, because the action it's actually called Detail(int id). Problem is doesn't behave the same.